# Group elements from multiple lists

Tags: java, list, groovy

I have following data structure:

[image]

Basically here I have a list, that contains other lists (their size can be arbitrary, in my case all 4 lists have size 2). I have to group so that lists that have the same elements go into one list (maybe not the best formulations, but I cannot formulate it better). In my case the results should be as follows:
`[72, 83, 127]` and `[110, 119]`.

If for example thirds sublist is contains elements `[83, 127, 55, 22]`, then the result should be as follows:`[72, 83, 127, 55, 22]` and `[110, 119]`. (So I have to include all sublist elements).

How can I do such thing in Java or Groovy?

Comment: I am totally confused as to how you want to decide which output list an element from the input should go into.

Comment: Well, sublist 0 contains 72 and 83. Sublist 1 contains 72 and 127. Due to the fact that the both contain 72, we merge them. Sublist 2 contains 83 and 127. Due to the fact that sublist 1 also contains 83, (or second contais 128) we also merge sublists 1 and 3.

Comment: So... are you saying that you want to merge the lists if the intersection between them is non-empty?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: what ever the values you have i.e 72, 83 etc, are you storing those as Integers or Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to process the whole list, one good option is to leverage groovy collection's [inject](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(groovy.lang.Closure)) method (added `println` to show steps):

```
def values = [[72, 83], [72, 127], [83, 127], [110, 119]]

def result = values.inject([], { res, value -> 
    println "res = $res | value = $value"
    def found = res.find {
        if (it.intersect(value)) {
            it.addAll(value - it)
            true
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        res << value
    }

    res
 })

 println result

 assert [[72, 83, 127], [110, 119]] == result
```

So that:

```
res = [] | value = [72, 83]
res = [[72, 83]] | value = [72, 127]
res = [[72, 83, 127]] | value = [83, 127]
res = [[72, 83, 127]] | value = [110, 119]
[[72, 83, 127], [110, 119]]
```

**EDIT**: the above solution is not working well in some cases, i.e.,

```
def values = [[72, 83], [72, 127], [83, 127], [110, 119], [47, 56], [56, 72]]
```

yields

```
[[72, 83, 127, 56], [110, 119], [47, 56]]
```

while if the list is sorted it yields (which I think it is the correct solution)

```
[[47, 56, 72, 83, 127], [110, 119]]
```

**EDIT (2):** A better solution that solves the previous issue (i.e., a list sharing elements with several lists of the result):

```
def values = [[72, 83], [72, 127], [83, 127], [110, 119], [120, 121], [121, 127]]

def result = values.inject([], { res, value -> 
    println "res = $res | value = $value"
    def found = res.findAll { it.intersect(value) }
    println "  -> found = $found"

    if (!found) {
        res << value
    } else {
        res.removeAll(found)
        def merged = found.collect({ it + value as Set }).flatten() as Set
        println "  -> merged = $merged"
        res << merged
    }

    println "  => res = $res"
    res
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "while if the list is sorted"?

Comment: [[47, 56], [56, 72], [72, 83], [72, 127], [83, 127], [110, 119]]

Comment: Ok, I will just use .sort() method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is java implementation using maps. First we convert ArrayList to the map i.e.  key=integerInList + value=NoOfOccurrence.  Then we just search each element in the map if the element has more than 1 occurence then we just add to the respective group ( Set).

```
public static void find() {
    //Input Data
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(Arrays.<Integer>asList(72, 83));
    list1.add(Arrays.<Integer>asList(72, 127));
    list1.add(Arrays.<Integer>asList(83, 127));
    list1.add(Arrays.<Integer>asList(110, 119));

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    //Convert Input Data to Map
    for (List<Integer> integers : list1) {
        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            int integer1=1;
            if (map.containsKey(integer)) {
                integer1 += map.get(integer);
            }
            map.put(integer, integer1);
        }
    }

    Set<Integer> group1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> group2 = new HashSet<>();
    //find and build groups
    for (List<Integer> integers : list1) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            if (map.containsKey(integer)) {
                if (map.get(integer) > 1) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            group1.addAll(integers);
        } else {
            group2.addAll(integers);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("group1 = " + group1);
    System.out.println("group2 = " + group2);
}
```